# Can Bazel aspects access the current target's java_common.provider

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

As part of our efforts to create a bazel-maven transition interop tool (that creates maven sized jars from more granular sized bazel jars),
we want the `aspect` that runs on `bazel build` to access the target's `java_common.provider` in order to fetch the jars and ijars from it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, that's possible.

You can use the `java_common` module in an aspect implementation the same way you would use it in a rule implementation.

From the documentation on [java_common.provider](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/java_common.provider.html):

- `java_common.provider.compile_jars` and `java_common.provider.transitive_compile_time_jars` refer to the ijars used at compilation time
- `java_common.provider.transitive_runtime_jars` refer to the full jars used at runtime.

The full jars at compilation time are not yet available, but someone is working on exposing this feature. (Issue #3528 on GitHub.)

Make sure you also read the blog post on this topic: https://blog.bazel.build/2017/03/07/java-sandwich.html

Comment: That's great news! specifically how do I access the provider? I wasn't able to find it in `ctx.rule.attr` nor in `target`...

Comment: found it under `ctx.rule.attr.deps`: 
`for dep in ctx.rule.attr.deps:
          if java_common.provider in dep:`

Comment: OK, so can the `java_common.provider` be accessed from the `target`? I need to know what are the java outputs of the current target, not of it's dependencies...

Comment: Yes, you can access it via `target[java_common.provider]`